# HTTPS Post data from Lambda function for an Alexa Skill

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I know that there are methods for sending a `GET` request with a vanilla Alexa Lambda function, but does the same thing exist for `POST`ing data to an `HTTPS` URL?

I want to post data to a URL when the user fires a certain intent in my skill.

Comment: Did you get any solution? @Optimus

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are.

This is a [tutorial on creating POST method with JSON payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html#api-as-lambda-proxy-expose-post-method-with-json-body-to-call-lambda-function) from Amazon Doc

Personally, I would prefer to modulate and separate out the code dealing with HTTP out from the Alexa Skill, and put it into another Lambda function. Of course, it's totally optional, but here are my reasons:

- modularity for better debugging
- cleaner code if you have [multiple skill states](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/tree/v1.0.25#skill-state-management).

If you are looking for some code example, I use to have a [project that did similar job](https://github.com/AlexXiong97/alexa-skill-with-arduino-webclient), hope you'll find the documentation helpful in some way.

Comment: I think he wants to post from a Lambda, not to a Lambda.